# I get errors when writing to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that records working data. Then I insert this array into the request.

```
async function setJobs(jobs) {
    const insertFieldsOfJob = [];
    for (const key of jobs) {
        const jobFields = [
            `'${key.job_id}'`,
            `'${key.description}'`,
            `'${key.verified}'`,
            `'${key.amount}'`,`,
            `'${key.title}'`,
            `'${key.ctime}'`,
        ];
        insertFieldsOfJob.push(`(${jobFields})`);
    };
    const jobsIds = (await db.query(Jobs.writeJobs(insertFieldsOfJob))).rows;
    return jobsIds;
};
```

Here I am writing to the job details database

```
class Job {
    static writeJobs(jobsDetails) {
        const sql = `INSERT INTO JOBS (JOB_ID, DESCRIPTION, VERIFIED, AMOUNT, TITLE, CTIME) 
                VALUES 
                    ${jobsDetails} 
                        RETURNING ID`
        return sql;
    }
}

module.exports = Job;
```

I get data

```
jobs {
    job_id: 1,
    description: test,
    verified: false,
    amount: 500.00,
    title: test,
    ctime: 1564461408000,
}
```

And I get errors

```
error: invalid integer value: "500.00"
```

```
error: the value "1564461408000" is out of range for type integer
```

Why it happens? I refer to the properties of the object as a string.

Comment: Well that mean you have given `Int` type to your columns when you should be giving `Float / Double` for `amount` and `timestamp / date-time` for `ctime` depending upon your DB.

Comment: @prakash-thete I for all specified type `varchar 220`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use String() and remove some parentheses.

```
async function setJobs(jobs) {
    const insertFieldsOfJob = [];
    for (const key of jobs) {
        const jobFields = [
            `${String(key.job_id)}`,
            `${String(key.description)}`,
            `${String(key.verified)}`,
            `${String(key.amount)}`,
            `${String(key.title)}`,
            `${String(key.ctime)}`,
        ];
        insertFieldsOfJob.push(`${jobFields}`);
    };
    const jobsIds = (await db.query(Jobs.writeJobs(insertFieldsOfJob))).rows;
    return jobsIds;
};
```

Comment: No error, but the value is not wrapped in single quotes

Comment: Why do you nedd single quotes? The values are already strings